# Troubles on analyze integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^x+e^{2x}+e^{3x}}$ by comparison test

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm having troubles with comparison test for analyze convergence on integrals.

I have to analyze this by comparison test

$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^x+e^{2x}+e^{3x}}$

Researching I found that I need a $\int_0^\infty f(x) \le \int_0^\infty g(x)$ and

1.- If $\int_0^\infty g(x)$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $\int_0^\infty f(x)$ also converges

2.-If $\int_0^\infty f(x)$ diverges $\Rightarrow$ $\int_0^\infty g(x)$ also diverges

I'm stucked because I don't really know what's next, I would try something like reduce the denominator to $e^x$ but I'm not really sure if this works like that or how should I find a $g(x)$ that can work properly

If someone could help me I would be grateful

Comment: You are on the right track. You have $$e^{x} + e^{2x} + e^{3x} \ge e^{x} \implies \frac{1}{e^{x} + e^{2x} + e^{3x}} \le \frac{1}{e^{x}}$$

Comment: Just as an aside, if you want to compute this integral, you'd need to multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^x$ and then do the substitution $u = e^x$.